# remove strings from variable in php

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am using  "AngularJS" invoice template for my project. It will display currency symbol in sub total text box. It is okay to showing it but when i enter data to the data base it also added this (LKR- Sri Lankan Rupees) , I just want to remove that LKR and add only value to the database. I used following method for that but it did not work. Could anyone please help me to solve this ?

```
$inoice_subTot = strstr($inoice_subTot1, 'LKR');
```

Ex: Remove LKR from LKR56.90 and just add 56.90 to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp)

**Code**

```
$inoice_subTot1 = 'LKR56.90'; 
$str2 = substr($inoice_subTot1, 3);
```

**Output**

```
56.90
```

> This will **remove first 3 letters** in variable

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/egnt-2fs3)

Comment: Even though your solution will work in this scenario, what the OP actually meant to ask was that he will will give a sequence of characters that he will provide as an input that should be sliced in the output. Consider an example where the currency code is of two characters only

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma actually in sri Lanka currency format is LKR comes first. So this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
//ltrim or trim should do the trick
//$inoice_subTot = trim($inoice_subTot,'LKR');

$inoice_subTot = ltrim($inoice_subTot,'LKR');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP function trim for remove certain string

```
  $str = 'LKR56.90';
  $inoice_subTot = trim($str,"LKR");
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression would work well for this. The pattern `\D*(\d+\.\d+)` should slice off a currency symbol of any length and place the amount into the `\1` capture group. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to implement this.